# Getting the real width after using min-width

Tags: jquery, width, css

The goal is to get the width of an object after it has conformed to min-width and min-height standards:

```
.myclass{
   min-width:100px;
   min-height:100px;
 }
```

The original image was 100 x 50 and became 200 x 100 after being appended to the page.
However when using jquery to call for the images width the result is 100px (the min-width).

```
var object_width = $('.myclass').width();
```

Comment: you need `img.onload` to be sure before checking width

Comment: Unfortunately `.onload` did not work.  Instead I managed to take the stored values from another portion of my code.  This solves the problem for me but if anyone has a more generic solution please share!

Comment: @ivoilic : is my answer generic enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wait for the image to be loaded before checking the width of the element. You can do this by attaching a function on the `load` event of the image, e.g:

```
$('img').load(function(){
   // Check the width of .myclass here
})
```

Heres a little jsfiddle example proving the concept: http://jsfiddle.net/TjHY2/1/